# How to make my JSF resources dynamic?

Tags: jsf, jsf-2.2

What I would like to do is to programatically set my resources e.g. in GraphicImage and use for distribution e.g. dispatch images from other servers.

My thought was to extend the resource handler and depending on the library and id render the appropriate urls. Is that the way to go or is there a more elegant solution?

--update

The use case is the following: I have users that are uploading images/videos which I want to store in separate datastore and I also would like to have the ability to dispatch my js and css from other locations. The traditional way to do this to my knowledge is to have a front load balancer that handles the redirection but I would like to handle this on the application.  One way to do this is to use full urls and set the base url in a configuration file and construct the full url. Another way which is what I would like to do is to extend the resource handler so that whenever I use a specific library eg.js or userimage to actually return a dynamic url so that I can easily set the location of my files. What I am not sure is if this is an good solution? If this has any implication and if there is simpler more elegant way to achieve the same result?

Comment: Can you at least give some kind of example of your approach, I am having a hard time visualizing your description. Why not just have image URL's in a database or resource bundle then you can refer to any number of servers or content delivery networks for serving your graphics?

Comment: You are correct about my post, it is not clear. I will update. It should also answer your question